# Long press to capitalize

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, keyboard

The [ergodox-ez](https://ergodox-ez.com/) keyboard have a nice feature that they describe as follows:

> [image]
>
> #### Dual-function Keys
>
> Tap your Z key, and it sends the letter Z as expected. Press and hold it down... and it becomes Alt. That is the power of dual-function keys: When tapped, they send a character. When held, they act as a modifier. Alt, Ctrl and friends have never been easier to reach.

I've configured mine so that every letter becomes its upper-case version when held down (so, light tap on <kbd>a</kbd> produces "a", a longer tap produces "A"), but I don't always have access to that keyboard and I miss that feature.

Is there any way of achieving the same thing independently from the hardware?

There is something quite similar [that exists for AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=31588&sid=3aa08273025c97a213879664a4e67ee3) (cf. also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44583538/2657549)), but I'm looking for a Unix-(preferably KDE-) solution.

Maybe there is something with [autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but I made my own solution because I couldn't find a proper way to mimic the [morse](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15574-morse-find-hotkey-press-and-hold-patterns/) function from AutoHotkey. Albeit it uses low level permission to read /dev outputs.

This is an example output from /dev/input/event

```
Event: time 1677080541.072921, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9d
Event: time 1677080541.072921, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1677080541.072921, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1677080541.319094, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9d
Event: time 1677080541.319094, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 2
Event: time 1677080541.319094, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1677080541.348759, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9d
Event: time 1677080541.348759, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 2
Event: time 1677080541.348759, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1677080541.379604, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9d
Event: time 1677080541.379604, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 0
```

The output goes from 1 (key press), 2 (key held), and then 0 (key release).
Using this I was able to make a simple script to send commands according to certain patterns in keystrokes. I made this specifically for using with the media controls, but if the timings were adjusted it could serve this function. Here's the [github](https://github.com/picklepissjar/ev-morse).

Edit:
This may also be of [interest](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=509849#p509849), it is a solution using [AHK_X11](https://github.com/phil294/AHK_X11).

Comment: Very nice, thanks for sharing!